# iOS UIView adding and removing subviews throughout the code

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview

I have a blue line in my app that displays an artificial horizon.
I want to be able to display and remove it at different parts of the code (.m).
Can I declare it (lineViewHorizon) universally.

At present I can make it appear/disappear only within the same section/method of code.

I presume this can be done?

```
UIView *lineViewHorizon = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, pageTopMargin+inthorizon, self.view.bounds.size.width, 2)];
lineViewHorizon.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:lineViewHorizon];
[lineViewHorizon removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to display and remove it at different parts of the code

In order to remove a view from another view, you'll need a pointer to the view that you want to remove. You can get that either by finding the view in the view hierarchy, perhaps using `-viewWithTag:`, or you can keep a pointer to the view in an instance variable (or property). Either way, the key thing is that you need a pointer to the view so that you can send it a `-removeFromSuperview` message.

Comment: I was trying the second approach but am grappling with the syntax. I have put a -(void) Property in my .h but not sure how to declare the pointer in the .m.

Comment: Can I declare this as  UIView *lineViewHorizon; after the @implementation? That works but is it good practice?